# Health Care industry data for Hospitals/Urgent Cares, etc

Tags: data-request, usa, medical, analysis

Is there a database available (free or not) that contains health care industry data for hospitals, urgent care, clinics, their location, ownership information (parent/child relationship), and other information for the USA?  [CMS](https://www.cms.gov/) tracks doctors and "some" hospitals however the industry uses ambiguous terms for what is a hospital vs medical center or primary care center vs urgent care.

Does anyone know of a source for statistics in the US Health Care industry?

Comment: https://data.medicare.gov/data/hospital-compare

Answer (score 2):

American Hospital Association has data on hospitals, their ownership, size, admissions etc https://www.ahadataviewer.com/

Comment: Thank you Daria.  I guess I am just looking for more detailed information beyond hospitals: urgent cares, surgery centers, medical practice groups, etc...

Answer (score 2):

For hospital data I found this website that lists hospital information, including location, hospital type and some quality measures. See: https://hospitalcaredata.com/directory/

I found this website with a list of urgent care facilities, but no statistical data. See: http://urgentcarelist.com/

Comment: Great, thank you!  This is definitely a huge step forward to compiling healthcare industry data.

Answer (score 1):

I work at Quandl and we have a database called Organisation for Economic Co-Operation and Development.

I searched for "US hospitals" within the database and it turned results showing data for number of hospitals in the US, number of hospital beds, number of hospitals per million, number of publicly owned hospitals etc. Hope this helps.

See: https://www.quandl.com/data/OECD-Organisation-for-Economic-Co-operation-and-Development?keyword=US%20hospitals

Note: You can always search for other terms or leave the search field blank.

Comment: Wow this is great, I'll keep looking through it.  There's a lot of health care industry data that I'm looking for in each state: urgent cares, clinics, hospitals, surgery centers, etc...  The health care industry is full of the ambiguous terms so I was wondering if there was one central location that defines this place as a hospital and this place as a medical center.